# My redux thunk Axios calls return empty objects in my Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using tmdb and redux-thunk to make async calls and return the data. I've tried every way possible and only empty objects show up in my store even though when I log the results I see the data there.

I tried to map through the results with no luck. If I return it by the index for example (example[0]) it does show the results of the first index.

Screenshots of store and console - https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK0tO.jpg

```
export const fetchVideoKeys = urlArray => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(isLoading(true));
    axios
      .all(urlArray)
      .then(
        axios.spread((top, pop, up, now) => {
          console.log(top)
          dispatch(getVideoKeys(top));
        })
    );
  };
};
```

```
const initialState = {

    videoKeys: {
        topRated: [],
        popular: [],
        upcoming: [],
        nowPlaying: [],
    }
};


export default function VideoTrailerReducer(state=initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case VideoTrailerActionTypes.GET_VIDEO_KEYS:
            return {
                videoKeys: {
                    topRated: [action.payload]
                }
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    movieIds.popular.length > 1 &&
    movieIds.topRated.length > 1 &&
    movieIds.upcoming.length > 1 &&
    movieIds.nowPlaying.length > 1 &&
      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(
          fetchVideoKeys([
           createUrls(movieIds.topRated, videoUrls),
           createUrls(movieIds.popular, videoUrls),
           createUrls(movieIds.upcoming, videoUrls),
           createUrls(movieIds.nowPlaying, videoUrls)
          ])
        );
      }, 1000);
  }, [
    movieIds.topRated,
    movieIds.popular,
    movieIds.nowPlaying,
    movieIds.upcoming
  ]);
```

```
export const getVideoKeys = data => {
    return {
        type: VideoTrailerActionTypes.GET_VIDEO_KEYS,
        payload: data
    }
 }
```

I expect the store to show the results but is only returning empty objects.

Comment: Hi, it might help to see your `getVideoKeys` function, this is the bit that actually dispatches your payload

Comment: Added getVideoKeys function

Comment: Based on your image it looks like you're logging promises. You may have to 'await' the result before dispatching.. do you know the type of `top` that you're `console.log`ging?

Comment: Yes the typeof is an Object.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screengrab, I expect you wish to dispatch `data.results` from your ajax response. Right now you are dispatching the promise.

Try playing around with  `console.log(top.data.results)`
Your code example assumes that your url list will have just 4 array items, so where you have this:
   `axios.spread((top, pop, up, now) => {`
`top` will be the response from the first url passed.

A codepen calling your api might help.

[Also you're exposing your api key in the image]

Comment: Ty , changed the picture.